# Initializing a List<T> using an EntityCollection that has a foreign key

Tags: linq, frameworks, collections, entity

I'm trying to initialize a List using results from the entity framework. Here is the error:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Domain.Entities.Person] ToList[Person](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Domain.Entities.Person])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

```
 public List<Domain.Entities.Event> Events
        {
            get
            {
                Entities context = new Entities(connectionString);

                return (from c in context.Events.Include("EventPeople")
                        select new Domain.Entities.Event()
                        {
                            ID = c.ID,
                            Title = c.Title,
                            Description = c.Description,
                            Date = c.Date,
                            People = (from ep in c.EventPeople
                                     select new Domain.Entities.Person()
                                     {
                                         ID = ep.ID,
                                         Name = ep.Name
                                     }).ToList<Person>()
                        }).ToList<Domain.Entities.Event>();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to execute first and return an IEnumerable then with linq to Objects create a list

```
var events = (from c in context.Events.Include("EventPeople")
                    select new
                    {
                        ID = c.ID,
                        Title = c.Title,
                        Description = c.Description,
                        Date = c.Date,
                        People = (from ep in c.EventPeople
                                 select new Domain.Entities.Person()
                                 {
                                     ID = ep.ID,
                                     Name = ep.Name
                                 })
                    }).ToList();
return events.Select(e => new  Domain.Entities.Event()
                    {
                        ID = e.ID,
                        Title = e.Title,
                        Description = e.Description,
                        Date = e.Date,
                        People = e.People.ToList()
                    }).ToList();
```